# Unable to set up O365 license with powershell

Tags: powershell, office365

I'm trying to set up licences on Office365 users with powershell for a future migration.

To do this, I've firstly put a list (with a powershell script) of existing users/licences in a CSV file. It looks like this:

```
Users,Licence
toto@mycompany.com,"MYCOMPANY:LICENCEXXX","MYCOMPANY:LICENCEVISIO"
titi@mycompany.com,"MYCOMPANY:LICENCEXXX","MYCOMPANY:LICENCEWORD"
tata@mycompany.com,"MYCOMPANY:LICENCEXXX","MYCOMPANY:LICENCEEXCEL"
....
```

(For information, I'm sure about the licence name because I get them with the command `Get-MsolAccountSku` )

For the future of the migration, I'm currently doing another script to set up the licence automatically on existing users, by taking information on the ***Licence*** column of the CSV file

I do it like that:

```
$csv = Import-Csv C:\output.csv

$toto = $csv[1].Licence

Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName toto@mycompany.com -AddLicenses $toto
```

And here is my problem, when I launch this script I've got this error:

```
Set-MsolUserLicense : Unable to assign this license because it is invalid. Use the Get-MsolAccountSku cmdlet to retrieve a list of valid licenses.
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName toto@mycompany.com -AddLicense ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Set-MsolUserLicense], MicrosoftOnlineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.InvalidUserLicenseException,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.SetUserLicense
```

It looks like the licence doesnt exist, but if I do the command manually, it work.

Also, if I put the variable **$toto** like that in the script, it work:

```
$toto = "MYCOMPANY:LICENCEXXX","MYCOMPANY:LICENCEWORD"
```

I don't understand why it work when I do it manually, and if I extract it from a CSV file it don't work.

Hope you can help me,
Thanks

Comment: Well, your CSV contains two comma-delimited headers. Your data rows contains three comma-delimited data fields. So `$csv.Licence` only contains the first license in each row. This means your license update using the CSV vs. the manual way are not the same.

Comment: @AdminOfThings Thanks for your comment.
Even when I do with a ";" delimiter it do the same.
The output of the  $csv[1].Licence variable is good, it look like that: "MYCOMPANY:LICENCEXXX","MYCOMPANY:LICENCEWORD"

Comment: If that is exactly how the output looks, then it is a string rather than an array. If it were an array like the manual assignment of `$toto`, then each license would be unquoted and on a separate line in the output. You are not correct to say that `$csv[1].licence` is the same because it is impossible based on the CSV example you have provided. Maybe your actual CSV is a bit different than what you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume the following code executes as desired:

```
$toto = "MYCOMPANY:LICENCEXXX","MYCOMPANY:LICENCEWORD"
Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName toto@mycompany.com -AddLicenses $toto
```

`$toto` is an array of two strings. Each string is a license name. See below for its output:

```
$toto
```

**Output:**

```
MYCOMPANY:LICENCEXXX
MYCOMPANY:LICENCEWORD
```

In order for `-AddLicenses` to be passed an array of two license names per CSV row, your CSV sample must be tweaked. This is because your header row has two comma-separated values. Each of your subsequent data rows have three comma-separated values. So you need to either add a third header or combine the second and third data fields (the two license names) into one field. `Import-Csv` expects perfect alignment of header count to data field count on each row.

We will attempt combining the licenses into one field and note the subtle difference in the quoting as we are quoting the entire field rather than each individual license. This process is called qualifying the text.

```
$csv = @'
Users,Licence
toto@mycompany.com,"MYCOMPANY:LICENCEXXX,MYCOMPANY:LICENCEVISIO"
titi@mycompany.com,"MYCOMPANY:LICENCEXXX,MYCOMPANY:LICENCEWORD"
tata@mycompany.com,"MYCOMPANY:LICENCEXXX,MYCOMPANY:LICENCEEXCEL"
'@

$csv | ConvertFrom-Csv | Foreach-Object {
    Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $_.Users -AddLicenses $_.Licence.Split(',')
}
```

`$_` is the current object (row in this case) processed by `Foreach-Object`. `$_.Licence.Split(',')` creates an array of two license strings by splitting the licence data at the `,` character. Note that the use of `ConvertFrom-Csv` here is simply because I am processing CSV data as a string rather than from a file. If reading from a file, you would simply use `Import-Csv file.csv | Foreach-Object {`.